# Removing days from date columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a date column in pandas data frame as following

| Date | Department Cash flow |
| --- | --- |
| Friday, 1 April 2022 | 1550 |
| Thursday, 26 August 2021 | 2550 |
| Wednesday, 9 September 2020 | 1551 |

I want to remove the days on the left of actual dates including the comma as in the Date column so that it looks as in

| Date | Department Cash flow |
| --- | --- |
| 1 April 2022 | 1550 |
| 26 August 2021 | 2550 |
| 9 September 2020 | 1551 |

This will help me organise the data as per the chronology in the dates.

Comment: You split the value of every date in your table at `, ` and use only the second part as value.

Comment: Any reason to not just do `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` and use the result from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sting function in pandas

```py
import pandas as pd

# Data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Date": [
        "Friday, 1 April 2022",
        "Thursday, 26 August 2021",
        "Wednesday, 9 September 2020"]})

# Arrange Dates
df["Date"] = df["Date"].str.split(",")\
    .str[-1].str.rstrip().str.lstrip()
```

I added `rstrip` and `lstrip` to remove heading and trailing whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the data type of your date. Is it a string or a datetime format?

If its a string you can use slicing methods, otherwise you can use the datetime library to stringify your date and then slice it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).